# How to repeat a delta using SAP_CDC connector from Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, factory, sap-data-services, odp

We've just started with ADF and are using the SAP_CDC connector to connect to generic data sources in ODP. This all works but one time the update in Azure failed yet the ODP request was flagged as confirmed. Our only option seemed to be to reinitialise the data source by deleting the subscription in ODQMON and dropping the table in Azure.

In BODS we're able to specify a timestamp to repeat extraction from and there is SAP doco on this (2399296 - How to recover a delta load for ODP Extractor in Data Services).

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to repeat a delta request in ADF
2. In ODQMON the subscription only appears as the technical/timestamp - there is no descriptive label, and the icon next to the subscription is missing (greyed out).
   [image: missing label]

Will appreciate any answers.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Is it possible to repeat a delta request in ADF?**

In my view Yes, it brings last delta records (which are not pulled thru last delta info pack) and latest delta records as well - given in MS Q&A  [861785](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/861785/how-to-handle-delta-load-from-sap-bw-openhub-table)  by @*KranthiPakala-MSFT*.

**In ODQMON the subscription only appears as the technical/timestamp - there is no descriptive label, and the icon next to the subscription is missing (greyed out).**

As per my analysis on referring to @*PremShanker*  article in this  [blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2020/12/25/operational-data-provisioning-simplified/)  it appears as timestamp.

Refer to the MS  [Doc1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/sap-change-data-capture-prerequisites-configuration)  for the SAP CDC connector in Azure Data Factory and  [Doc2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/sap-change-data-capture-debug-shir-logs)  for frequent debugging issues!

Comment: Thanks, I'm encouraged that there is a solution.
However I'm not sure if/how it works. If I look at the options for sap_cdc I see the 'Recovery' extraction mode but it doesn't offer any timestamp to recover from?